# Difference between VPN and VLAN

Tags: vpn, vlan

Just curious about know is there any difference between VPN and VLAN?

If yes how?

Is it possible to setup VLAN and VPN if I have these equipments?

I have - 1 dell laptop with wired and wireless lan card, One iPad2, One samsung galaxy S mobile, One Dlink router DIR-515 D4, and ethernet cables 1, the router has wifi also.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are big differences.  A VLAN (Virtual Local Area Network) exists inside a Layer 2 device on the network side.  It is used to segregate networks at Layer 2 inside of a network.

A VPN (virtual private network) is designed to allow you to connect from outside a network, to the inside of the network, by using VPN services (typically on a VPN server).  This allows you to connect inside the network from home, using servers, printers, and anything inside the network from outside of it.

The VLAN slices up a large network into smaller, more manageable pieces.  A VPN allows remote connection inside of a network.

EDIT:
Some things to note regarding VPN and VLAN configurations:
1) Instructions for setting up a VPN server are specific to the operating system, type of VPN used (PPTP, L2TP, OpenVPN), and to some degree network configuration. It is outside the scope of a Q&A site like this. 2) Instructions for configuring and testing a VLAN are also outside the scope of a Q&A site like this. You will need to do some research (probably take some classes) for those answers.

Comment: how can i setup a VPN server and how to test the VLAN?

Comment: 1) Instructions for setting up a VPN server are specific to the operating system, type of VPN used (PPTP, L2TP, OpenVPN), and to some degree network configuration. It is outside the scope of a Q&A site like this. 2) Instructions for configuring and testing a VLAN are also outside the scope of a Q&A site like this. You've asked the difference between the two, and I've answered. You will need to do some research (probably take some classes) for those answers.  3)  If you have another/more questions to ask, please do it separately.  Since this question is answered, maybe mark it as such...

Comment: Nicely done. A well-composed answer. I'd suggest incorporating the majority of this comment into your answer as well.